# Why does voltage regulator heat up and starts to switch the supply when it is used for driving a high-power LED?

Tags: led, voltage-regulator, led-driver

The regulator is an [LM2596HVS](http://hmsemi.com/downfile/LM2596HV.PDF) (max. supply voltage: 63 V) and it is connected to a Cree high-power LED. The regulator is part of an off-the-shelf buck converter.

It makes silly noises when the circuit is closed and heats up quite a lot (only when connected to the power LED).

After a few seconds, the LED starts to blink. The LED can take 6-12 V, however, it starts to blink even below 5 V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXhO48.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: The regulator chip does not work by itself, it needs the other components around it to work, so I presume that is a block diagram of the module? Which module it is and what is the voltage output set to? There is no resistance for the LED and if that is a constant voltage regulator module, it can't be connected to LED directly. The LED should be driven with a constant current, not constant voltage.

Comment: @Justme I don't think I could my hands on to schematics of the module but it is very commonly available off-the-shelf module. https://www.amazon.com/4-5-60V-1-25-30V-Lm2596hv-Switching-Regulator/dp/B00W8UTRJA/ref=sr_1_3

Comment: Have you wired the LED correctly? Where is the link to the LEDs data sheet?

Comment: @Andyaka Yes! https://www.cree.com/led-components/media/documents/ds-XHP70.pdf

Comment: Is the LED configured for 6V or 12V? To what output voltage have you set the DC/DC converter?

Comment: @ocrdu for 6V and I have tested it for voltage between 3-6V. it only takes longer for it start to blink at lower end of the range but it surely happen. Also, LED functions perfectly when directly connected to a lithium cell (3.9V at the time of testing).

Comment: And what voltage have you set the DC/DC converter to?

Comment: @azad.parinda:  You got lucky with the lithium battery.  The LED can handle a lot of current, and the battery (luckily) can't deliver enough to destroy the LED.  Even more luck:  The battery doesn't "see" the LED as a short circuit.  If you short circuit a lithium battery, you can get a fire or explosion.

Comment: @JRE I don't understand your point. are you saying that it is not right to drive an LED with a battery? If LED gets damaged , wouldn't it cause an open circuit instead of a short circuit?

Comment: It is absolutely wrong to drive an LED straight off a battery.  LEDs need a current limited source of power.  Your battery will try to deliver as much current as your LED will draw - and the LED "wants" it **all.**  You got lucky in that your battery couldn't deliver enough to destroy the LED, and that the LED couldn't draw enough to damage the battery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally, you would use a current source to drive an LED. Your DC/DC converter is a voltage source, and nothing is limiting the current through the LED.

Your DC/DC converter can deliver a continuous current of 1.5 A, and 3 A peak. Depending on its configuration (for 6 V or 12 V), the LED can pull more than that, and nothing is keeping it from doing so because you haven't put in a resistor to set the LED current.

What probably is happening is that the DC/DC converter overheats because of the high current, goes into thermal shutdown, cools off, starts up again, etc., making the LED blink.

You must put in a resistor to set the LED current. Calculating the resistor value requires the datasheets and knowing if the LED is configured for 6 V or 12 V, and to what output voltage you have set, or want to set, the DC/DC converter.

Example: If you configure the LED for 6 V and set the DC/DC converter to 7.5 V, the resistor would have to drop 1.5 V at, to make things work with your DC/DC converter, its maximum constant current of 1.5 A. So, R = V/I = 1 Ω. Dissipation then is 2.25 W, so a 5 W resistor will do. The LED would be working at about a third of its maximum drive current.

Comment: I used a 680ohm 5W resister in series earlier but it limited the current too much which resulted in led to not even light up. If I set the regulator to 6V what should be the limiting resistance? Any suggestions for better regulator with higher amps?

Comment: If you set the DC/DC converter to 7.5V, the resistor would have to drop 1.5V at, to make things work with the DC/DC converter, its maximum constant current of 1.5A. So, R = V/I = 1Ω. Dissipation would be 2.25W, so a 5W resistor will do. The LED would be working at about a third of its maximum drive current. Check the math yourself, please.

Comment: Thanks. BTW how do you tell at what voltage LED has been configured? I have taken it apart from a circuit where it was being driven by 1 lithium cell. With no additional circuits attached, wouldn't an LED function for its maximum limit?

Comment: The datasheet of the LED you linked to says "configurable to 6 V 
or 12 V by PCB layout". That's all I know. If it drops any other voltage, or wants another current, than specified in the datasheet, you have to redo the math. And no, a LED on its own doesn't limit its own current.

Answer (score 4):

The module has a constant voltage output.

It can't be directly connected to drive a LED.

LED needs to be driven with constant current supply.

Comment: LED works fine connected directly with a Lithium battery cell. Wouldn't current of a lithium battery drop gradually as it discharges?

Comment: That would be a completely different scenario and has nothing to do with the scenario of driving the LED with constant voltage regulator module.